# apply_filters() function

Tags: php, functions

I have used **apply_filters()** while retrieving the content from WordPress post like:

```
$content=$query_val->post_content;
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

When I was using ***apply_filters()*** the ***apostrophe( ' )*** in my text shows some characters.After I have removed ***apply_filters()*** it shows properly.

So please explain it clearly!! What it is doing?
I have referred this link [Referal_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270989/what-does-apply-filters-actually-do-in-wordpress), but I'm not clearly understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the characters are html entities like &nbsp &lt or &#60 then use php's default html_entity_decode() function to get the content in proper text format.

Comment: i had an attempt with html_entity_decode(), it doesnot work in some cases.After that only i came to try like this.

Comment: You will have to use both strip_slashes as well as html_entity_decode.
Exactly like this:
html_entity_decode(strip_slashes($arg));

where $arg is the variable you are passing to remove special characters.

Comment: is apply_filters() compulsory to get the content?

Comment: `html_entity_decode(strip_slashes($arg));` shows Call to undefined function strip_slashes() in fatal error

Comment: Sorry, the function is stripslashes($arg) and not strip_slashes().

Comment: super ji :) ok i will test and catch you

Comment: no,its not helpfull